# The Comic book version of X: The Man With the X-Ray Eyes (1963)

Tags: movie, comics

I have dim memories of reading the [comic book version](https://www.comics.org/issue/17886/) of the Roger Corman film *[*X: The Man With the X-Ray Eyes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X:_The_Man_with_the_X-ray_Eyes)* (1963). I remember reading it on summer vacation at Cape May, New Jersey, but what I mostly remember of the comic book itself is the end when James Xavier described a terrying cosmic vision.

His dialog in the movie goes like this:

> Saved? No. I've come to tell you what I see. There are great darknesses. Farther than time itself. And beyond the darkness... a light that glows, changes... and in the center of the universe... the eye that sees us all.

A post [here](https://moviechat.org/tt0057693/X/58c708de4e1cf308b9392f8a/What-Did-He-See-at-The-End-SPOILERS?reply=6370b073484db8623f6c68b2) at quotes the comic book version as a more terrifying:

> "There are great darknesses coming to devour us all! They are larger than the stars, larger than the *galaxies* of stars! They are *coming!*"

---

I would like to see an image of that panel from the comic book, if anyone can provide it (and maybe also an image of the last vision Xavier sees from the movie for comparison).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Said panels from the comicbook.

[image]

[image]

Said scenes from the movie for comparison